# Нужно ли выделять запятыми фразеологический оборот "кому не лень"?

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология

Забава в парках, по которой, кому не лень, колотили молотом.

Подскажите, нужно ли выделять запятыми "кому не лень" в данном предложении?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятые не нужны, так как это сочетание синонимично ‟все подряд”. Вот пара примеров из Нац. корпуса:

> Что эта симпатия не вполне бескорыстна, пусть судачат кому не лень, но «борцы за идею», не имеющие мало-мальского влияния, уже никому не нужны. [Валерий Выжутович. Совершенно не секретно // «Московские новости», 2003]
> Тут о вас на площади судачат кому не лень. [Дарья Донцова. Уха из золотой рыбки (2004)]
> Тоже повторяют кому не лень: «Спасение утопающих ― дело рук…» [Михаил Чулаки. Новый аттракцион // «Звезда», 2002]

Comment: В конце простого предложения ударение переходит на оборот, а вы найдите, где он в середине без запятых.

Comment: Вообще не важно, где здесь стоит это сочетание: оно по смыслу как ‟все подряд”, а поэтому его обособление как обособление подлежащего.

Comment: Раз не важно, найдите примеры.

Comment: Заплатите мне за это.

Comment: Ну тогда вы не правы и позиция важна. Вероятно, не можете найти.

Comment: То, что это сочетание как ‟все подряд” и обособление этого сочетания будет как обособление подлежащего, — очень сильная позиция. Прямо сильнее некуда.

Comment: Вы рассматриваете лишь одну сторону медали. Поэтому не факт, что вы правы.

Comment: Всякое может быть.

Comment: Да, кстати, полное сочетание ‟все кому не лень” пишется в Нац. корпусе без запятых, так что обособления в любом случае не будет. Я не знаю другого человека, которым так бесстыдно пользовались все кому не лень. [Галина Щербакова. Косточка авокадо (1994)]

Comment: А у Розенталя ‟все кому не лень" может писаться с запятыми.

Comment: Ну и прекрасно!

Answer (score 1):

1. Указанное предложение использовалось в сканворде,  и там оборот был выделен запятыми. https://www.graycell.ru/answer/

*Забава в парках, по которой, **кому не лень**, колотили молотом* (7 букв)

Таким образом, надо проверить правильность обособления. Я предполагаю, что запись **верная.**

**Пояснение**

1. ***Кому не лень*** – устойчивое сочетание, которое не обособляется, так как имеет значение одного слова.

Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка
***Кому не лень.*** Разг. Экспрес. Всякий желающий (может сделать, предпринять что-либо). Стоят с самого лета на станции скирды прессованного сена, гниют под дождём кипы, растаскивают их кому не лень, а погрузки нет (Н. Сухов. Казачка).

2. В то же время  фразеологизмы обычно не обособляются в определенной позиции  (в данном случае нет обособления после глагола), то есть **структура предложения очень важна.**

Сравнить: Он шёл как во сне. – Люди, как во сне, шли молча.

А Иван, кряхтя, полез под дубовое корыто и лежит там как убитый. Наутро, как убитые, заснули мужики.

3. В приведенном предложении оборот находится **в препозиции**, и практически трудно найти такие примеры без обособления. Но вот примеры, где оборот обособлен:

**Кому не лень**, так слушай*  (В.И. Даль. Пословицы русского народа)

***Кому не лень**, зайдите в тему.

4. **Вывод**

Желательно оставить вариант с обособлением: *Забава в парках, по которой, кому не лень, колотили молотом.*

Следует также учесть, что это **сложное предложение**, и его содержание более понятно при обособлении оборота.

Answer (score 0):

Фразеологический оборот — "все кому не лень". Следовательно, у вас не фразеологический оборот.

Comment: В большинстве фразеологических словарей указаны все варианты: кому не лень, кому только не лень, все кому не лень, все кому только не лень. В "Малом академическом" [тоже](https://lexicography.online/explanatory/mas/%D0%BB/%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C). И я думаю, что Вы не поняли вопрос.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за уточнение.